# Not able to parse input using KeyValueTextInputFormat in hadoop mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, delimiter

My input file is like this:

```
Key1 : Value1,Value2
Ket2 : Value3,Value4
```

In mapper, I want to get a key where ":" is the delimiter. For this, my code is like this:

```
JobConf conf = new JobConf(newCount.class);    
conf.set("mapred.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator", ":")    
conf.setInputFormat(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
```

I have also tried:

```
conf.set("key.value.separator.in.line.input.line", ":")
```

but was unable to parse. When I print the key, it prints like this --> `key:`
and I want to print only ---> `Key`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the new API (hadoop 2.x), I see from the [API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/KeyValueLineRecordReader.html) that the correct parameter to set is `mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator`.

I.e., use `mapreduce`, instead of `mapred`.

**UPDATE**: It could also be that the delimiter ':' appears more than once in your input. For example, if an input record is `key1: : value1 value2 value3`, then you would get something like what you describe in your question. If such is the case, then you should choose the delimiter properly, so that it appears exactly once.

Comment: perhaps the value starts with a ':' character, or the key ends with a ':' character? I mean, does ':' appear more than once in the line?

Answer (score 1):

If using Hadoop 2.x, parameter is

> mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator

Can you share a sample of your input data??

Answer (score 0):

[How to change the default key-value output seperator in Hadoop MapReduce](http://www.unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/04/can-we-change-default-key-value-output.html)

For KeyValueTextInputFormat the input line should be a key value pair seperated by `"\t"`

```
Key1     Value1,Value2
```

By changing default  seperator, You will be able to read as you wish.

For New Api

[Here is the solution](http://www.unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/09/can-we-change-default-key-value-input.html)

```
//New API
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("key.value.separator.in.input.line", ","); 
Job job = new Job(conf);
job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
```